# Question about field values comparison (for instance for tdclock in Beamer)

Tags: beamer, textfield, tdclock, setcounter

I have a question about the tdclock package that seems to be connected to the problem of comparison of fields. I want to make a beamer with tdclock and I need to introduce a counter, called for instance cronom whose value is identical to the output of the command \cronominutes of the tdclock package (the output is a box but I am obviously interested in the number !). When looking at the content of tdclock.sty, it seems that the output of \cronominutes comes from a field called cronominutes since we can find a line like that :

```
\TextField[readonly=true,name=cronominutes, hidden=true, width=0pt, height=0pt,charsize=0pt]{}
```

My question is very simple : can I create a counter

```
\setnewcounter{cronom}
\setcounter{cronom}{??????}
```

what should I write in ???? to get exactly the value appearing in \cronominutes.

Sincerely yours.

Answer (score 1):

> can I create a counter

No, you can't.

tdclock uses javascript to insert the time when you *view* the presentation, latex can't know about this at the time you compile the document. You can't change the latex counters retroactively when you view the document.

---

Depending what you are actually trying to do with your counter, there might be other approaches, e.g. using javascript etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @Expoju You're welcome!